# Implementing some kind of simple loop in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, loops

I have a table which has these columns: `id, text, parentid`. And when a row is a root item (doesn't have any parent item), then `parentid = 0`.

What I want to do, is find `text` of the first root (root of root of ... root of item) of a specific item.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT parentid FROM cat WHERE id = 1234 --returns 1120
SELECT parentid FROM cat WHERE id = 1120 --returns 1011
SELECT parentid FROM cat WHERE id = 1011 --returns 0. So this the first root.
SELECT text FROM cat WHERE id = 1011 --returns what I want.
```

I know it's easily possible with Loops, but I'm using `sqlite` which doesn't support loops.

So, the question is, is there any way to implement this in `sqlite` **without using any other scripts?**

Comment: You can use a [recursive cte](http://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

Comment: @Blorgbeard I can't understand how it works. Can you please explain it a bit more, and post it as an answer?

Comment: Oops, something was wrong in the example. (Last query, number should be 1101 not 1120) I just edited it.

Comment: I don't have time to spend on that right now, but maybe someone else will. There *are* copious examples on that page, you could probably figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recursive CTE will give you the desired result. Please note that the CTEs are available only in the latest versions of SQLite starting from [version 3.8.3](http://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html)

```
;with cte as (
  select id, parentid, text, 1 level 
  from t where id = 1234
  UNION all
  select t.id, t.parentid, t.text, cte.level + 1 
  from cte inner join t on cte.parentid = t.id 
  where cte.parentid <> 0)
select * from cte where parentid = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the necessary SQLite version. I had to update my SQLite libraries.